# How to put a digit grid in a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm programming a Sudoku solver
so far it is nearly complete.
But I want to show in the empty cells the candidates in a number matrix
I do not see any solution

I exspect for candides 2,4,6,9 a matrix
  | |2| |
  |4| |6| 
  | | |9|
for a DatagridView cell

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to display 3x3 matrix in each DataGridViewCell?

Technically, you coud set a monospace font and set

```
DataGrodView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
DataGrodView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
```

...and fill each cell with text-formatted array of spaces and numbers, like

```
1  -  -
-  6  -
9  -  -
```

I used dashes to display the effect, where should be spaces too, probably (don't know Sudoku).

However, I would rather display the Sudoku in a picturebox as a generated graphics, where you have more freedom. I have no experince with Sudoku, but works great for planning, gannt graphs, etc.